# Finding values of a constant in a probability distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

A probability distribution for the random variable $X$ is defined by:
$$\mathbb{P}[X=x] = K\cdot(0.9)^x,\quad x = 0,1,2,\ldots$$
It is asked to find $\mathbb{P}[X\geq 2]$.

When there is a domain for $x$, that is $[0,n]$ I am able to find the value of $K$ by applying the rule that sum of probabilities add up to $1$. But in this case I am not given a domain for $x$...

$$\mathbb{P}[X\geq 2] = 1 - \left(\mathbb{P}[X=0]+\mathbb{P}[X=1]\right) = 1 - 1.9K,$$

so the answer is $0.81$... how do you get this?

Comment: Please use a proper formatting. The domain of $x$ is given in your very first line: $x=0,1,2,\ldots$ means $x\in\mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sum of probabilities must still be one:

$$1=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} P(X=n)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} k \left(\frac9{10}\right)^n=\frac{k}{1-\frac9{10}}=10k$$

Hence $k=\frac{1}{10}$.

Comment: I dont understand how you get the K/(1-9/10) .... where did the n go?

Comment: @confused Summation of the geometric series: for $a$ with $|a|<1$, you have $1+a+a^2+\cdots=\frac{1}{1-a}$. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series).

Comment: Are there any other rules I should be aware of when dealing with such questions? Other important series/sequences to be aware of?

Comment: @confused Any positive series may represent probabilities, so that would be many series to be aware of :-) Depending on the perversity of your teacher, the series may be rather easy, or a nightmare.

Comment: could you please provide a link to different types of geometric series? I would like to be aware of some, for future reference. It would be much appreciated.

Comment: There is only one kind, see the link above. But something that appears quite often is the series $1a^1+2a^2+\cdots$ or more generally $\sum_{n=p}^\infty n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-p+1) a^n$. See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/906492/calculating-sum-value) for an idea of the computation. Usually it involves derivating a known series one or several times.

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

The domain is essentially, 0 to infinity.

$$\sum_{0}^{\infty}k(0.9^x) = k{(1+0.9+.0^2+.9^3+\cdots)} = k(\frac{1}{(1-.9)})=1 $$

$$ k = 0.1$$

$$P(X>=2) =1 - 0.1*0.9^0+0.1*0.9^1 = 1-.1-.09 = 0.81$$

Comment: How does (1+0.9+0.9^2+0.9^3) = 1/(1-0.9) ??